# Else body is executing in System Verilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I am working on a module in System Verilog with the following code:

```
module my_module (input             [7:0] rd_i // rd_i = 00001001
                 ,input             [7:0] rs_i // rs_i = 10010010
                 ,output logic  [7:0] result_o // result_o = 00001010
);

    always_comb
        if ((rd_i << 4) & 8'hF0 == rs_i & 8'hF0) begin
            result_o = 'b0101;
        end
        else begin
            result_o = 'b1010;
        end
endmodule

module my_module_tb();
    logic [7:0] rd_i = 'b00001001;
    logic [7:0] rs_i = 'b10010010;
    logic [7:0] result_o;

    my_module uut (
        .rd_i(rd_i),
        .rs_i(rs_i),
        .result_o(result_o)
    );
endmodule
```

It seems like I should expect result_o = 5, but instead it equals 10.  I don't understand why my if condition is evaluating to be false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is operator precedence. IEEE Std 1800-2012, section *11.3.2 Operator precedence*, shows the `==` operator has higher precedence than the binary `&` operator.  This means your code behaves like the following, with parentheses added:

```
    if ((rd_i << 4) & (8'hF0 == rs_i) & 8'hF0) begin
```

Since `rs_i` is not equal to `8'hF0`, the `if` clause is false.

To get your desired behavior, add parentheses as follows:

```
    if ( ((rd_i << 4) & 8'hF0) == (rs_i & 8'hF0) ) begin
```